# laravel 5.8 eloquent: has many relations model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am creating event information system and want to show tags in posts/show.blade.php.

But I got an error.

> Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

In posts table, I have category_id.
And I created post_tag table.

Do I need to create another new table ?

> How to show tags in show.blade.php ?

Please give me a hand.

post.php

```
   public function tags() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);

}
public function hasTag($tagId)
    {
        return in_array($tagId, $this->tags->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }
```

tag.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

category.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

create_posts_table

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('organizer');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('place');
        $table->string('map');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
        $table->text('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

create_categories table

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

create_tags table

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

post_tag table

```
Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('tag_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

ResultsControllere.php

```
public function show($id,Post $post)
{
    $post= Post::find($id);
    $post->category;
    $post ->tags;
    return view('posts.show',compact('post'));
}
```

show.blade.php

```
Tags:
  <div class="tags">
     {{ $post->tags->name }}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your defined relationship `post has many tags` so you cannot access the `one to many relationship` directly you may have to `loop` through to get the tag detail e.g name

```
<div class="tags">
     @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
     {{ $tag->name }}
     @endforeach
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`$post->tags` should return a collection so there is no property `name`.

Your `show.blade.php` code should be:

```
<div class="tags">
    @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
        {{ $tag->name }}
    @endforech
</div>
```

Comment: How your answer is different than mine?

Comment: @SalmanZafar its not different. we just posted at the same time.

Comment: better avoid posting same answers repeatedly if there is nothing new to add